# One day yom tov for someone who spends every chag in Israel?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, eretz-yisrael, yom-tov

I met someone who lives outside of Israel almost full-time and who told me that, because he's in Israel for each of the *shalosh r'galim* every year, he keeps only one day *yom tov*. Is this (the applicability of that criterion alone) a valid halachic opinion, and, if so, whose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rabbi [Shlomo Zalman Aurbach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Zalman_Aurbach) rules this way in a responsum ([Minchat Shlomo 1:19:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15096&st=&pgnum=191)). After reading it I'm not sure if he also requires that they own a permanent dwelling in Israel to live in during Chag or not; CYLOR for a final ruling (as usual).

Comment: It is mashma that he requires a residence, but the note of his students say that that would only be if you cannot find residence.  but today with the abundance of hotels it would not be necessary